dragula how to configure more than 2 containers
I searched and tried for hours with no success. Now I need help.
I'm using dragula on three containers. The following code is what I'm using now. It works, but it's not exactly what I need.
dragula([
document.getElementById('containerOne'),
document.getElementById('containerTwo'),
document.getElementById('containerThree')
],{
copy: function (el, source) {
      return source === document.getElementById('containerOne')
},
accepts: function (el, target) {
      return target !== document.getElementById("containerOne")
},
revertOnSpill: true
})

What it does:

Copy Element from containerOne to containerTwo
Copy Element from containerOne to containerThree
Move Element from containerTwo to containerThree
Move Element from containerThree to containerTwo
Do not allow any element into containerOne

But what I need is (please note difference on line 4)

Copy Element from containerOne to containerTwo
Copy Element from containerOne to containerThree
Move Element from containerTwo to containerThree
Copy Element from containerThree to containerTwo
Do not allow any element into containerOne

How do I configure the extra copy function ?
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks !
